# How can I clean out a dryer vent which exits under my backyard deck?

Tags: dryer, vent

Since I cannot reach the end of my dryer vent cover to push all the lint out with the long brush kit, what is the next best way to go about cleaning it? Would using a shop vac hose work and suck it all back towards the dryer?

The pipe is quite long stretching through the front of my house to the back. Roughly 30ft.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I used a leaf blower last year to blow the lint out of my dryer vent. It worked like a charm.

Comment: You mean, you used a leaf blower? Otherwise, how did you hook the snow blower's output to your dryer?

Comment: yeah leaf blower. Just disconnect the vent hose from the wall and shoot the leaf blower in the pipe.you should get a bunch of lint outside

Comment: Thanks. Please edit that info into your answer; readers shouldn't have to review comments to understand.

Comment: The problem is I have to remove parts of my deck to get to the vent exit. So I was hoping sucking it up would work but if not, then I'll have to deal.

Comment: You don’t need to access your vent exit if you use the leaf blower. You blow It from inside

Comment: Got to give this a + the only thing I would be concerned about would be a splice that may blow apart. The high flow should pick up the lint and push it to the end of the line sounds like it could work if not over pressurized.

Comment: That, or the modern three-flap louvers that you often see. Blowing from the inside might cause a massive pileup at the exit, making the situation much worse.

Comment: might not work for him, but it worked for me. If it doesn't work, he is still gonna have to pull some boards off the deck to get to the exhaust vent.

Answer (score 0):

Using a vacuum from inside will work only if there isn't a backflow prevention flap on the exterior vent exit. There should be.

I'd look at pulling a couple deck boards up and gaining access to your vent exit. You might then extend it to a location that's more accessible using smooth, rigid aluminum duct.

Comment: I did just redo my deck this summer, that is when I discovered it. It does have a flap on the end of it and the only way I could extend it would be to pull out each composite board from the house and turn the duct to the left 90 degrees and run it under the deck to the side of it. Would the duct need to be inside of anything or can is just lay on top of the rocks?

Comment: Do NOW what you should have done while "redoing the deck this summer" - create an access panel in the deck that you can unscrew once or twice a year. This is already a VERY long vent, making it longer reduces the performance even more and gives lint more places to build up. Honestly, I'd look at "what's the shortest path from the dryer to outside" and cut a new vent in; if you can move the dryer location to make that easier/shorter, consider doing that as well. The dryer will work better and the odds of burning your hose down will drop.